# Does anyone know a good Website comparing all the PBX/IP telephone solutions?

Tags: cisco, voip, sip, telephony

I'm looking for a good website dressing a comparative analysis of the most popular telephony solutions resellers (Cisco, Avaya, Siemens, Microsoft, etc...).
I already found a very nice work comparing Cisco and Avaya, but it's not all. What is interesting for me are the performances, the evolutivity, all the technical data, the size of the hardware for a few different configurations, etc.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a ton of information here:
http://www.voip-info.org/

It's mostly related to the open source solutions so it may not be what you're looking fo but there is still a good amount of info. Especially on the phones themselves.

Comment: Thanks, looks good, but isn't it only for VOIP? I don't see anything about analog nor SIP.

Comment: SIP is a VOIP protocol, and there is info about analog connections about halfway down the page where it says: "Connecting VOIP to the PSTN".

Comment: Ok, thanks, I didn't pay enough attention at the first place... I'll check this deeper.